# Como se chama o padrão representado por esta classe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, orm, padrão-dao

Gostaria de saber que tipo de classe é essa `DaoDeAutenticacao`, cujo esqueleto escrevi abaixo. Apesar do nome não acho que seja um DAO (*Data Access Object*), seja lá como ele for definido, e sim alguma outra coisa (um *Data Mapper*?). Gostaria de saber que nome tem esse padrão, se é que tem um.

A intenção dele não é mapear uma única tabela do banco e sim um conjunto de tabelas relacionadas, apesar do exemplo estar mapeando uma só.

O objeto Java `CentralDeAlarme` populado com os dados do banco e retornado pelo método `autenticar()` é um objeto do interesse do domínio da aplicação. Aliás, como é chamado esse objeto? É um *Data Transfer Object* (DTO)?

```
public class DaoDeAutenticacao {

    ...

    public CentralDeAlarme autenticar(String senha) {
        CentralDeAlarme resultado = null;

        try {
            // Abre conexão com o banco

            // Monta e chama statement
            // SELECT c.id, c.fabricante, c.modelo FROM centrais c WHERE c.senha = senha;

            resultado = new CentralDeAlarme(id, fabricante, modelo);

            return resultado;

        finally {
            // fecha conexão com o banco
        }
    }
}
```

Usando a classe DaoDeAutenticacao:

```
CentralDeAlarme central = daoDeAutenticacao.autenticar(senha);
if (central == null) { // autenticação falhou
    ...
    return;
}

// autenticação bem-sucedida
Logger.log("Central autenticada: " + central);
...
```

A classe CentralDeAlarme:

```
public class CentralDeAlarme {
    private final int id;
    private final Fabricante fabricante;
    private final Modelo modelo;

    // getters
}
```

Comment: Certamente não é DTO. Na verdade nem sei se entendi bem a pergunta.

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta, por favor veja se ficou mais clara.

Comment: O código novo parece ser o um DTO.

Comment: E o `DaoDeAutenticacao`, seria o quê?

Comment: Eu acho esquisito, mas pode ser só eu que não sei fazer essas coiaas que o pessoal faz por aí :)

Comment: Então não é um DAO, é só uma classe esquisita? :P

Comment: Não considero isso um DAO.

Comment: Entendido. Vou ter que pesquisar mais então para saber o que é considerado um DAO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Será um DAO?**
 
Como já mencionado, o padrão DAO é usado para separar APIs ou operações de acesso a dados (baixo nível) da lógica de negócios (alto nível). Simples assim! Uma abordagem para implementação desse padrão, seria: Uma interface, uma classe concreta para implementá-la e um VO (Value Object), sendo este último um POJO que conterá apenas atributos, getters, setters e nada mais.

**Será um *Data Mapper*?**
 
Imagine de um lado uma classe modelo (o bom e velho POJO) e do outro lado a base de dados. No meio, objetos "mapeadores" que movem os dados entre os objetos do modelo e a base, mantendo um independente do outro. Pois bem, de forma simples essa seria a essência de um Data Mapper. Esse padrão pode se tornar custoso conforme a complexidade do modelo relacional.

**Como é chamado esse objeto?**
No caso do *CentralDeAlarme*, seria um *DTO*, ou um *BO* ou quem sabe um *VO*...

**DTO (Data Transfer Object)** - Objeto simples para transferir dados de um lado para o outro na aplicação.

**BO (Business Object)** - Encapsula a lógica de negócios para um objeto. Contém apenas as propriedades do objeto de negócio, contém apenas os métodos de negócio ou os dois.

**VO (Value Object)** - Usado basicamente para exibir dados na camada de apresentação (há controvérsias). De fato, o objeto CentralDeAlarme me parece um DTO.

**Como se chama o padrão representado por esta classe?**
Algo parecido com um DAO ou com particularidades de um. Como sabemos, Padrões não são escritos na rocha. Vai que essa abordagem, dentro de um contexto específico, representa uma evolução para algo melhor. Vai quê…

Comment: Olá Allan. Como você falou, no Java um DAO precisa de interface e implementações "trocáveis" entre si, pois sua intenção é trocar a implementação de forma transparente para os objetos de domínio, então não chega a ser o caso do código da pergunta. Além disso as operações do DAO vão mais para o lado de CRUD, que é o que pedem os objetos do domínio. A pergunta se se trata de um Data Mapper eu perguntei por exclusão, olhando os enterprise application patterns do Fowler, mas não entendi o suficiente para cravar uma definição. Talvez seja um, em todo caso. E a outra classe provav//te um DTO mesmo.

Comment: Bom, como não há sentido em cogitar possibilidades sem ter a definição bem acertada (isto é, se é um data mapper ou não), vou dar a questão como respondida. Obrigado e apareça mais!

Comment: É isso Piovesan! Nesse caso tão específico vamos por aproximação e bom senso. Eu que agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

**DAO ( Data Access Object )** :É um padrão para persistência de dados que permite separar regras de negócio das regras de acesso a banco de dados. Ou seja aqui deve conter toda a a manipulação de banco de dados como por exemplo consultas, inserções updates...

**Business**: Aqui você concentra a regra de negócio, você poderá chamar os métodos da classe DAOs e implementar sua regra de negócio.

**Entity ou Value Object**:
 São os objetos de persistencia, que representam as tabelas de maneira orientada a objetos. Exemplo : Usuario, Perfile...

**Data transfer object**: são objetos de transferência de dados, que podem ser utilizados para fazer conjunções, gerar relatórios e etc.

Answer (score 0):

Então se o objetivo é agrupar várias informações de tabelas diferentes pode-se utilizar o conceito de DTO já que são conjunto de dados que serão transferidos em um objeto e que não representam uma unica entidade.
Outra classe que você poderia utilizar que talvez se enquadre no modelo são os POJO's (Plain Old Java Object) são classes simples que tem como objetivo apenas a movimentação de informações sem métodos internos além de getter, setters e construtor, sem interfaces, heranças ou frameworks externos

Comment: Olá Guilherme, seja bem-vindo ao site. Faltou responder a primeira pergunta (a do título) em relação à classe DaoDeAutenticacao. Outra coisa, o nome do padrão que você descreveu como POJO na verdade é o padrão Java Bean. São POJOs também, mas têm sentido mais amplo.

Comment: Realmente, é um java bean, obrigado por esclarecer!